# Segmentation Fault when run loop 41881 times

Tags: c, file-io, segmentation-fault

I am writing a C program that reads a text file and parses the data in it into various fields.  The text file I am reading from is very large though (31MB) and when I run the program on a text file that has 41880 lines of input everything works fine.  I will ultimately need to read from text files that are much much larger than that though.  So when I increase the lines to 41881 though I get a segmentation fault.  Any ideas?

Comment: Without the source of the portion that's breaking, it's pretty much impossible to work out what's wrong.

Comment: 31 MB isn't that large, so I suspect you have a bug, rather than simply running out of memory.  Can you post your code?

Comment: Sorry, my clairvoyance isn't what it used to be. Care to provide some of the code that is having the problem?

Comment: Who voted this up???

Comment: Again, we need the source code, otherwise we will just be doing some pointless speculation.

Answer (score 2):

You are trashing memory somewhere along the way and it's finally hitting you at line 41881.

If your platform is supported, try running under [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/).

Comment: or just under gdb and do a bt when it segfaults

Comment: @ninjalj - that is a very different thing.  gdb will show you your context at the moment the crash setfault occurs.  But if the code that trashes memory does not immediately trigger a crash (which is unfortunately quite common), knowing where the crash occurred may not help you find where the actual bug is.